# Removing comments from aspx files only in SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer

Are there any ways to remove all the comments from aspx files only in SharePoint Designer? I found that the **Optimize HTML** in SharePoint Designer only deal with HTML only.

I am also open to any software that is able to help me to remove all the comments from aspx files.

Comment: No. You have to open the files one-by-one and delete the comments. If they aren't accessable through SPD, you have to log onto the server and do the procedure there.

Comment: @Dandroid, you must be kidding right? I have 50+ files and opening each and every one of them is a pain.

Comment: Nope. Good luck, have fun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only hope for you is to use Find/Replace command with a robust Regular expression to find the comments and then replace with blank.

I believe SharePoint supports Regular expressions. As an example, I have written an expression that works for simple one line comments as shown below:

[image]

The expression I used is:

```
\<!--[^(--\>)]*--\>
```

DISCLAIMER: You need to thoroughly test your regular expression before you perform replace function.